# ubuntu 12.04 installation problem on windows 7 64bit

Tags: 12.04, wubi

```
06-26 20:57 ERROR  TaskList: Extraction failed with code: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 450, in extract_diskimage
Exception: Extraction failed with code: 2
06-26 20:57 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
06-26 20:57 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
06-26 20:57 ERROR  root: Extraction failed with code: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 450, in extract_diskimage
Exception: Extraction failed with code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have alternatives to wubi:

a. If you want to **try** ubuntu without installing it, you can burn it on a cd/dvd or on a usb.

There are info on how to burn a live cd or create a live usb at the ubuntu download page:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows
- http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

  Then you can boot using that cd/usb. (Note: You might have to set the cd device or usb as the boot device from BIOS setup.)

b. If you want to **install** ubuntu, you can use the live cd and select "Install ubuntu"

Wubi is not recommended for a number of reasons, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29#Limitations